# Use ManyToMany field in add object raise needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-2.2

I have two models : `Exam` and `Question`. Each question has point that **automatically calculate** in each exam.

So this is my files:

```
#Models.py
class Exam(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    title = models.CharField()
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    answer = models.TextField()
    points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

#Forms.py
class ExamForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = '__all__'

#Views.py
if form.is_valid():
    new_exam = form.save(commit=False)
    # Some modify goes here. 
    new_exam.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect('view_exam')
```

I did customize `save()` method of `Exam` model to this:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.point = 0
        for question in self.questions:
                self.point += question.point
        super(Exam, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I got this error:

```
"<Exam: NewObject>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

***How can I do this without raising any error?***

**My goal:** For each new exam that created, calculate the points of questions of this exam and put them into the `points` field of `Exam` model.

Comment: You cannot access `self.questions` before the object is saved. Call the `super().save()` method first, then access the questions. But this is all pointless because: 1. `Exam` doesn't have a field `point` so setting `self.point` doesn't make sense because it's not saved and therefore lost once you exit the `form_valid()` method. 2. `questions` haven't been saved yet (because you didn't yet call `form.save_m2m()`) so with new objects, nothing happens.

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to do with your custom method, then we might help suggest an alternative. Right now you should just delete your custom save method because it serves no purpose. Then everything will work.

Comment: Finally, what I must do ?Please write your answer.  @dirkgroten

Comment: Ok, I write my purpose in my question. @dirkgroten

Comment: I wrote what I was looking for. @dirkgroten

Comment: your Exam model doesn't have a `points` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never a good idea to save things to your model that can be calculated from other fields/tables in your database, especially if this depends on other models. Too easy to forget to update the value when at some stage you create a new `Question` for example. You'll just get inconsistency in your db.

Delete your custom `save()` method because it doesn't do anything.

If you want to know the total number of points, add a custom getter on `Exam` that calculates this on the fly:

```
#At the first of models.py -> from django.db.models import Sum 
@property
def points(self):
    if self.pk:
       return self.questions.all().aggregate(Sum('points'))['points__sum']
    else:
       return 0
```

Or with your kind of summation:

```
@property
def points(self):
    if self.pk:
        point = 0
        questions = self.questions.all()
        for question in questions :
            point += question.point
        return point
    else:
        return 0
```

With this property, you can do `exam.points` anywhere in your code and it will be up-to-date.

Comment: So you suggest not to do that and actually do it at the `Views.py` level? @dirkgroten

Comment: No, sorry, changed the order of my arguments. Don't add a field points and don't save it is what I'm saying. Calculate it on the fly by adding the method I gave above (as property) to your model Exam. If you really want to save it, you could do this at the view level, yes, but I'd advise against it because you will need to remember to do this at the view level for all the views that modify questions and exams.

Comment: `Sum` is not valid! And how can I get this property in my view? @dirkgroten.

Comment: I got this error when I use `exam.points` : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' @dirkgroten

Comment: You need to import Sum

Comment: And on which line do you get the operant error? I’m not doing any + operation in my code.

Comment: I didnt' import Sum and change it to `sum` and got this error. Now, everything is OK. Thank. @direkgroten